# Scala: why are parameters renamed?

Tags: scala

I am studying rxScal example at https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/0.x/examples/src/test/scala/examples/RxScalaDemo.scala

This example contains following code:

```
  o.subscribe(
      n => println(n),
      e => e.printStackTrace(),
      () => println("done")
    )
```

But the signature of subscribe is:

```
 def foreach(onNext: T => Unit, onError: Throwable => Unit): Unit = {
    asJavaObservable.subscribe(onNext, onError)
  }
```

I do not understand who renames `onNext` to `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n => println(n)` is an anonymous function (a function with no name) that takes an argument and acts on it. That argument is labeled `n` but it could have been `x` or `wwz`, or whatever.

When you pass that function as an argument to another function, the receiving function will give the received argument a name.  The first argument to `foreach` is labeled `onNext` but it could have been `x` or `zzw` or whatever. It is the name of the received function.  It doesn't matter what the name of that function was when it was passed to `foreach`, maybe it was anonymous and had no name, inside the `foreach` code it now has the name `onNext`.

Inside `foreach`, `onNext` is the name of a function that takes an argument and acts on it.  The name of that argument is unknown and immaterial to the `foreach` code.

So, in short, `onNext` hasn't been renamed to `n`.  They are, essentially, unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought that this is a named parameter and the function is just "println". I oversaw 'n'. Correct syntax is 'onName=println(_)'.

Answer (score 1):

You have given the signature of `foreach`, not `subscribe`. It looks like the signature of `subscribe` is:

```
def subscribe(onNext: T => Unit, onError: Throwable => Unit, onComplete: Unit => Unit): Subscription
```

this means that

```
n => println(n)
```

is a function which is executed when the next value of `T` arrives. Therefore `n` has type `T` and is bound to the incoming value. Similarly

```
e => e.printStackTrace()
```

is a function `Throwable => Unit` so `e` has type `Throwable` and will be bound to the error parameter given to `onError` of the `Observable`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it will be clearer if we remove some of the Scala magic so we can think about the code in more deliberate steps:

```
def subscribe(onNext: AnyRef => Unit, onError: Throwable => Unit, onComplete: Unit => Unit): Subscription = ...

val myOnNext: AnyRef => Unit = n => println(n)
val myOnError: Throwable => Unit = e => e.printStackTrace()
val myOnComplete: Unit => Unit = _ => println("done")

o.subscribe(myOnNext, myOnError, myOnComplete)
```